# .htaccess redirect all subfolder content (with and without ending slash) to same subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect the following URLs:

```
/gallery/image-1/
/gallery/image-1
/gallery/image-2/
/gallery/image-2
```

to `/gallery/`, but it's harder than what it at first seems. This is from the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*) /gallery/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

All URLs are initially redirected to `/gallery/`, but then it just keeps loading, as apparently this URL also goes under `^gallery/(.*)`, so it keeps redirecting to the same URL. After a few seconds, the browser gives me a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` message.

How can I edit the `^gallery/(.*)` statement to only cover URLs with something after the `/gallery/` URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `.+` instead of `.*` in your regex to make sure to stop redirecting when URI is `/gallery/`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(gallery)/.+$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, the + sign works like a charm! In the end I simply replaced the * with a +, and that was it, like this: RewriteRule ^gallery/(.+) /gallery/ [R=301,L,NC]. Why did you put "gallery" within parentesis in your example?

Comment: Ah that was just to avoid repeating `gallery` on both source and target of `RewriteRule`.