# .htaccess redirect to page within folder leads to repeating url segments

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to do the reverse of this [issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063341/htaccess-redirect-all-subfolder-content-with-and-without-ending-slash-to-same) I am trying to redirect users from a subfolder to a child page. This is my current rule that doesn't work:

```
Redirect 302 /boston /boston/info
```

Using this, if I go to `example.com/boston`, I get redirected to `example.com/boston/info/info/info/info/info/info`... and it keeps going.

I imagine I'll need to switch to a RewriteRule in order to prevent this duplication. How should I go about this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"/boston/info" - This should be the full URL you are redirecting too.

eg. www.website.com/boston/info

Comment: I tried adding the domain to the beginning of the destination, but it still adds /info/info/info and on and on. I don't know why.

Comment: Could you have the previous redirect cached in your browser?? Redirect 302 /boston www.website.com/boston/info will work as expected on almost every apache configuration. Could you also check the .htaccess file is the only one with redirects that is read?

Comment: I opened it in a new private browser window, so the cache seems to be clear. When I test it now I get a 500 server error when the rule is saved, but the site loads normal when the rule is commented out. I didn't see any conflicting rules in the httpd.conf.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite apache module installed?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed checkmark. I really appreciate your helping me solve this issue.